# What is the "referencing folder" for an angular project?

Tags: angular

Im trying to implement a 3rd party grid (https://www.lidorsystems.com/support/articles/angular/grid/grid-component.aspx) and I am following the instructions in the README file. The first instruction is to copy/paste the '/bin/integralui folder' into the 'referencing folder'. Im not sure what the 'referencing folder' is that they are talking about. The only thing I can think of is the angular.json file but thats a file not a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All projects have an associated working directory in which they execute. What the IntegralUI team is likely referring to by a "reference folder" is simply a directory that which you can reference via a standard path in your project.

I don't have any experience with Integral UI, but **a quick glance at their documentation reveals instructions to create a directory under the assets folder and name that subfolder integralui**

> To include resources that are used by IntegralUI components in your
>   project during build, you need to:
>
> Under assets folder create a subfolder named integralui Copy/Paste the
>   node_modules/integralui-web/bin/integralui/resources folder to it
>
> Add the following code under assets section in angular.json file:
>   "src/integralui/resources"
>
> Note This is required because Angular
>   compiler cannot detect resources that are outside the /src section of
>   your app. It is needed if you are using resources that are part of
>   IntegralUI Web, in your application.

Comment: thats kind of what i thought. it started to make more and more sense taking a closer look at it. thanks!